# Текст в flexbox съезжает

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
///css///

* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

.up {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 23%;
  display: flex;
}

.menubutton {
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.kek {
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
///html///

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dimabyte</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="up">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="menubutton">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="kek">|</a>
        <a href="#" class="menubutton">AboutMe</a>
        <a href="#" class="kek">|</a>
        <a href="#" class="menubutton">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#" class="kek">|</a>
        <a href="#" class="menubutton" style="display: none">Contact</a>
        <a href="#" class="menubutton">Contact</a>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="down">


    </div>


  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Приветствую!
Пытаюсь сделать меню. В нем пункт "About me" me съезжает вниз. Если пишу слитно, все норм. В чем дело?)
[image: Раздельно]

[image: Слитно]

Comment: чё то я смотрю и ни чего не съезжает - где проблема ?вижу только 4 пункт куда пропадает

Comment: "Me" становится ниже. А по замыслу должно быть одном ряду с остальными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы слова не переносились добавьте к menubutton свойство `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо!